# How to set value in child chart using parent's value.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have got the following chart structure and I would like to pass the `apiVersion` from `Parent-Chart` to `Child-Chart` but it's not working

**childChart/values.yaml**

```
apiVersion: ""
```

**parentChart/chart.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  - name: zookeeper
    version: 0.6.7
    repository: "file://../../zookeeper"
```

**parentChart/values.yaml**

```
zookeeper:
   apiVersion: "v2"
```

child

When I run `helm template parentchart .` I see no value in `apiVersion:`

This [SO Question](https://SO%20Question) matched my scenario but I am unable to make it work.

Comment: That looks like the correct syntax.  Do you have an example in `childChart` where `.Values.apiVersion` is being used?

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the syntax and I was able to resolve the issue

The issue was with the older version of `zookeeper` tar file which I **deleted** and then executed `helm dep up`

After updating the dependencies it worked as expected